# Riley Riddle in the game

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-clues, board-games

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #7: Board games](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/monthly-topic-challenge-7-board-games?cb=1).</sub>

---

> My first can *hold flags (No matches).*
> My second *lasts three months (No matches).*
> My last is *your attention (1 accurate match).*
> My whole is the game you're playing.

Obviously that isn't enough to solve the puzzle, so here are three cryptic clues to complete.

- 10 thousand as 12.25 (1 accurate match)
- How The Beatles make Help relies upon just very beginning (No matches)
- Bend down for no points (1 accurate match, 2 misplaced matches)

---

Can you find the word that matches the six clues?

Answer (score 21):

The Riley Riddle resolves to clue the board game:

> **[MASTERMIND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game))**

*My first can hold flags.*

> **MAST** - where on a ship one might find sails and flags.

*My second lasts three months.*

> **TERM** - 3 months is a common length of term for a school or university term to last.

*My last is your attention.*

> **MIND** and attention are synonyms of sorts.

*My whole is the game you're playing.*

> Together (with overlap) they make MAST + TERM + MIND = **MASTERMIND**. But hang on... 'the game *you're playing*'?!

We're not done yet. Because as well as solving this riddle we are also actually playing a game of this! (This is what the mentions of 'accurate' and 'misplaced' 'matches' after each line refers to...) So let's solve the 3 cryptic clues too to give us everything we need...

*10 thousand as 12.25*

> **XMAS** (12.25, i.e. Christmas Day) = X (10) + M (thousand) + AS

*How The Beatles make Help relies upon just very beginning*

> **RUJV** = R(-elies) U(-pon) J(-ust) V(-ery). This (or possibly NUJV) is the word *actually* spelled out by the Beatles on their album cover for [*Help!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help!):
>
>  [image: Help! album cover]
>
>  They had originally intended to spell 'HELP' but it didn't look as great as they'd hoped from an arty point of view apparently...

*Bend down for no points*

> **DUCK** - a double-definition for 'Bend down' and 'no points' (in cricket).

So altogether this gives us the layout of the board:

> ```
>  MAST ....
>  TERM ....
>  MIND B...
>  XMAS B...
>  RUJV ....
>  DUCK BWW.
> ```

> Here, 'B' indicates a **b**lack peg for an accurate (exact) match, and 'W' a **w**hite peg for a misplaced match.

We can now solve this to find the answer:

> **[XKCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xkcd)**.
>
>  The first 3 rows reveal that there is no A, E, M, R, S or T in the answer. Row 4 then reveals the answer begins with 'X'. Rows 5 and 6 together reveal that the remaining letters must be D, C and K (no U), and with the help of row 3 we can confirm that the 'D' goes last, then the 'C' in third position and the 'K' second.

Comment: I suspect there is one more step, based upon your last result

Comment: @TonyEnnis I thought that was a possibility myself too, but while solving it a Google search of the two key search terms led to no 'edition' of any relevance, and there appears to be no thus-far-unused information left in the puzzle to help narrow it down further. Unless of course the answer is anticipated to be rot13([Enaqnyy Zhaebr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randall_Munroe), nf KXPQ'f 'znfgrezvaq'), which is a possibility. I think the puzzle is sufficiently self-contained to not necessarily require an additional step though :)

Comment: I don't know how you do it.  that was impressive